# Создание DataFrame из значений другого DataFrame по условным правилам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дано: 
`df1` из трех столбцов - `Параметр, Время, Значение`. Наблюдения представляют собой пакет параметров, измеренных в одно и то же время, т.е так:

```
Параметр 1 -- Значение -- Время 1
Параметр 2 -- Значение -- Время 1
Параметр 3 -- Значение -- Время 1
Параметр 1 -- Значение -- Время 2
Параметр 2 -- Значение -- Время 2
Параметр 1 -- Значение -- Время 3
```

Требуется получить другой датафрейм, `df2`, такой, чтобы Параметры стали столбцами, времена - индексами, а в ячейках значения, например так:

```
Время   -- Параметр 1   -- Параметр 2   -- Параметр 3
Время 1 -- Значение     -- Значение     -- Значение
Время 2 -- Значение     -- Значение     -- NAN
Время 3 -- Значение     -- NAN          -- NAN
```

На практике такой паттерн не работает:

```
for col in tqdm(df_out.columns):
    condition = df_out.index == np.unique(df['Дата и время'])
    df_out[col] = np.where(condition, df[np.unique(df['Дата и время']) == df_out.index][col]
```

Подскажите, как это обойти? 
Спасибо.

Comment: Ошибки обычно имеют смысл такой, что размеры датафреймов, сравнимых в `np.where()` не совпадают 
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (381994,) (81647,) ()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может сделать с помощью [`pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)?

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   param  value  time
0      1     10     1
1      2     20     1
2      3     30     1
3      1     40     2
4      2     50     2
5      1     60     3

In [4]: df.pivot_table(index='time', values='value', columns='param')
Out[4]: 
param     1     2     3
time                   
1      10.0  20.0  30.0
2      40.0  50.0   NaN
3      60.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Гениально. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решить задачу в разумное время помогло введение вспомогательного датафрейма. Ниже код с избыточным для понимания комментарием:

```
# Для каждого столбца, результирующего датафрейма..
for col in tqdm(df_out.columns):  

# Сначала создадим промежуточный датафрейм, который хранит отфильтрованные по 
# каждому Параметру Значения и Время   
df_col = df[df.Параметр == col] 

# теперь, по каждой строке промежуточного датафрейма выполним...
    for raw in range(len(df_col)):

        # Выберем Время, Выберем Значение
        date = df_col.iloc[raw,1]
        value = df_col.iloc[raw,2]

        # В то место результирующего датафрейма, которое соответствует текущему Времени и Параметру
        # добавим Значение
        df_out.loc[date][col] = value
```

Comment: В целом перебирать DataFrame в цикле плохая практика. Если этого можно избежать, то лучше этого не делать

Comment: Да, комментатор выше предложил способ в одну строчку такой, который у меня занял полдня работы и минут 15 вычислений. Отдаю ответ ему